# Issue with undefined post request

Tags: javascript, rest

I want to make a blood management app and I am having issue for user registration if I want to send data everything is working but I am not able to post data through the post request through rest client.
Each parameter is undefined.

index.js

```
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const cors=require('cors');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const app=express();
const userRoutes=require('./route/userRoutes')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blood').then(()=>{
    console.log('connected to database')
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
})
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/users',userRoutes);

app.listen(3001,()=>{
    console.log('server working on 3001');
})
```

userRoutes.js

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const userController=require('../controller/userController')

router.post('/register',userController.registerUser);

module.exports=router;
```

userController.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../model/user');

exports.registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, role, gender, bloodtype, age, disease } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already exists' });
        }
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        const newUser = new User({
            name,
            email,
            password: password,
            role: role || 'user',
            gender,
            bloodtype,
            age,
            disease: disease || 'N/A',
        });
        await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'New User created' });
    } catch (error) {
        // console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server error' });
    }
};
```

user.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        enum:['user','admin'],
        default:'user'
    },
    gender:{
        type:String,
        enum:['Male','Female'],
        required:true,
    },
    age:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
    },
    disease:{
        type:String,
        default:'N/A',
    },
    bloodtype:{
        type:String,
        enum:['A+','A-','B+','B-','AB+','AB-','O+','O-'],
        required:true,
    },
});

const User=mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
module.exports=User
```

request.rest

using rest client

```
POST http://localhost:3001/users/register

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@example.com",
    "password": "securepassword",
    "gender": "Male",
    "age": 30,
    "bloodtype": "A+"
}
```

I am not able to send the post request send data through post request through the rest client the `req.body` is empty i.e. each parameter is undefined.

I want to send post data but not able to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that you are using Express.js and Mongoose to build a RESTful API for your blood management app. It appears that the issue lies in the way you are handling the request body.

To resolve the problem, try the following steps:

1. Enable the JSON body parsing middleware in your Express app by uncommenting the following line in your index.js file:

```
// app.use(express.json());
```

This will allow Express to automatically parse incoming JSON payloads.

2. Make sure that the Content-Type header in your REST client is correctly set to application/json when making the POST request.
3. Update your REST client request to include the correct URL path. In your case, the correct URL would be http://localhost:3001/register instead of http://localhost:3001/users/register. This is because you've already set the base URL for the user routes in userRoutes.js using app.use('/users', userRoutes).

Comment: We do not [allow AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).